# Custom List's New Form doesn't appear to another users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, newform

I created a custom list and I added columns in the list. Then I created a new webpart with the custom list into my webpage and I linked in my homepage this list's NewForm.aspx.

I'm adminstrator in the site, I can see new form and all items.  But when other users want to add new item this list they got error as follow. But they can see All Items page. How can I share this new form to other users.

Please help me? Thanks for advice..
[image]

Comment: Check whether those users have permission to add item in that list.

Comment: I checked permission but site members have read permission. How can I change this permission contribute instead of reading? @Unnie

Comment: Login as administrator --> Site settings -->Site permissions . Click Grant Permissions option on the ribbon . Give permission to the users from there. Give them contribute permission level

Comment: Thanks for advice but That's okey good information for define new users group permission. But I want to give permission for another users, only the custom list's newform.aspx. If I give permissions with this path, they can contribute all forms in my site. But I don't want this. I want to give permission only the my custom list's newForm.aspx. How can I give contribute permission for a customlist to another users. Is it impossible? @Unnie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting steps:

1. Go to your custom List. List Settings --> Permissions for this List.
2. Click Check permissions on the Ribbon.Check if the site user is having Contribute permission.

If not , break inheritance (Click Stop Inheriting Permissions).

Then Click Grant permissions , give those users Contribute permission.

Now these users will only have contribute permission on that library.